# Thymeleaf: Get a item from an arraylist by its index

Tags: java, arraylist, thymeleaf

I want to fill fields with strings i stored in an arraylist. How can i get a specific string out of my arraylist with thymeleaf?

(With this solutions i insert the full arraylist into my field)

```html
[...]
<div class="round r-of-2">
                <div class="bracket-game">
                    <div class="player top loss">
                        <tr th:each ="participant : ${participant}">
                            <td th:utext="${participant.name}">...</td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                    <tr th:each ="participant : ${participant}">
                        <td th:utext="${participant.name}">...</td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </div>
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```java
<tr th:each ="participant : ${participant}">
```

**To**

```java
<tr th:each ="participant : ${participant.list}">
```

Hope this help

Comment: hm, doesnt work: Property or field 'list' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList'.
Im looking for the thymeleaf syntax of something like: <td th:utext="${participant[index].name}">...</td>

Comment: Are u writing springboot project??